# Pre-check checkboxes in laravel based on data object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In laravel, I have a foreach loop around a data object which contains a name, context and type value. In my loop I show rows where the name is displayed with 2 different types of checkboxes. One is checkboxes for context and the other for type.

I need to add submitted values from these checkboxes to a vue component but before I can do that I need to pre-check on conditions.

If my object contains a value for context of Internal then I need that checkbox to be checked, and if it has type of Old then I need that checkbox to be checked.

How can I make this so that it properly pre-checks any checkboxes where `detail->context` matches a context checkbox value and same for type

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
<h2 slot="header">{{$detail->name}}</h2>
<div slot="context" >
    <h4>Context</h4>   
    <hr>
    <input type="checkbox" value='direct'   ref="existingContextNames" data-md-icheck  />
    <label>Direct</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value='internal'  ref="existingContextNames" data-md-icheck  />
    <label>Internal</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value='customer'  ref="existingContextNames" data-md-icheck  />
    <label>Customer</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value='third party'  ref="existingContextNames" data-md-icheck  />
    <label>3rd Party</label><br>
</div>

<div slot="type" >
    <h4>Type</h4>   
    <hr>
    <input type="checkbox"  value='new' ref="existingTypeNames" data-md-icheck  />
    <label>New</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value='old' ref="existingTypeNames" data-md-icheck  />
    <label>Old</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox"  value='mix' ref="existingTypeNames" data-md-icheck  />
    <label>Mix</label><br>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to echo the checked tag property with an in-line ternary operator:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{  $detail->context === "thing_to_compare" ? "checked" : "" }} >
```

gives you

```
<input type="checkbox" checked >
```

if `$detail->context === "thing_to_compare"` resolves true

Comment: but then can I just keep my value as is?

Comment: This does make sense but the inline code is breaking my html

Comment: Hmm what html does it return? Vanilla PHP tags might also work like `<?= ($detail->context === "thing_to_compare" ? "checked" : "") ?>`

Comment: Thanks, that got it